# ES6 Promises with nested Array.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a project in which I want one of the functions to return the modified 'player' object.

Imagine, if you have player which equals to (below is not real code, but logic is the same):

```
{
    id: 1,
    val: 590
}
```

and stats (which is array of objects) equal to:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        val: 400
    }
    {
        id: 2,
        val: 590
    }
]
```

The problem is that when I do nested mapping ( .map() ), my player is somehow returned (resolved) faster than map function ends iteration. However, I want it to return *only after* all iterations finish.

**What I tried:** I found solution that implements count and checks if it equals to the outter map function. It does not work neither, as either my code sends it too fast (before iteration is done), or does not resolve at all.

I would be very grateful to hear any suggestions, or even practices (should I do this way or no), as I am trying to solve this problem for almost 2 days.

This is how it approximately looks like (original one is more complicated):

Here is link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/j0ownf0m/

```
const do_magic_with_measurements = (db, data) => {
  let session = data.session;
  let player = data.player;
  let count = 0;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      session.Measurements.map(measurement => {
        player.Stats.map(stat => {
          if (measurement.Type === stat.Type) {
            /* Update maximum value */
            if (measurement.MaxValue === stat.MaxValue) {
              db.collection(SESSIONS_COLLECTION)
                .find({
                  PlayerID: ObjectID(session.PlayerID),
                  "Measurements.Type": measurement.Type
                }, {
                  "Measurements.$": 1
                })
                .sort({
                  "Measurements.MaxValue": -1
                })
                .toArray()
                .then(one_session => {
                  console.log(one_session);
                  if (one_session[0].Measurements[0].MaxValue == stat.MaxValue) {
                    // update maximum value if they were equal
                    stat.MaxValue = 0;
                  } else {
                    // otherwise set the next maximum value
                    stat.MaxValue = one_session[0].Measurements[0].MaxValue;
                  }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error;
                    .catch(error => {
                      throw error;
                    });
                  }
                }

            });
        });
        count++;
        if (count === session.Measurements.length) {
          resolve(player);
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: function `map` isn't async, you can do all your work and return a resolved promise (`Promise.resolve`)

Comment: Check the update

Comment: your resolve as i see it is inside the players.map function. Also map returns a new array, if you want to go over each and every player, then foreach should do just fine, personally I don't find the given code very reader friendly (one wonders where the maps are going through) and that count is absolutely unnecessary because the resolve has only one place, behind the players.map function. Also where do you define players? this is not part of the sample code. I don't even see the need for a promise here

Comment: Your code works fine despite having many stylistic problems. What is the reason you are using a promise here? Are you trying to offload the loops into another thread? You can't do that this way. The fiddle is long to read and doesn't do anything on execution.

Comment: @TamasHegedus in order to avoid callback hell

Comment: @Icepickle check the JS fiddle I attached in the end of the post

Comment: @alwaysone there is absolute no need for callbacks in your synchronous code

Comment: @TamasHegedus the thing is that it still does not work. I suppose that inner promise (when I do database query) returns itself despite the presence of mapping there.

Comment: @Icepickle but how then I find the maximum/minimum value in the database? The thing is that I need to remove one minimum/maximum value from the DB, and then find the next maximum/minimum value and assign it to 'player' object property.

Comment: I don't really understand underlying logic in your code, but I believe you can use `Promise.all` with all inner promises. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/b60uj0vs/ Just push all promises into an array, and when you're ready get combined output with `Promise.all`.

Comment: @alwaysone Your code in the question here, is completely different from the code in the jsfiddle (where you actually already work with promises to resolve db access). In jsfiddle, you are making the mistake of doing a promise in a promise, but resolve only in your map function (whilst the db promise is the slower one, and this should be the one to wait for)

Comment: @Icepickle as of JSfiddle - that's true. But, how do I wait till inner promise is done, and only after return/resolve the whole outter function/promise?

Comment: @wostex but I do not need to 'fire' two promises. I do DB query (promisified) based on conditions. In the fiddle, you can see that I firstly check if values are equal, then I only fire the db query (promisified). If not, I continue to the next cycle of iteration.

Comment: Why don't you push all these db requests (without `then` blocks) into an array and resolve them all with `Promise.all` ?

Comment: @awlaysone Are you find with using async/await pattern?

Comment: @Icepickle heard but never done before. Do you think they are going to solve this problem as I have nested map (which MUST HAVE BEEN blocking)?

Comment: Yeah, they would, though I must say, your "map" is completely useless there, it's just a fancy way of using a for loop that doesn't return anything. A very abstract way of doing the code I see in your jsfiddle would be something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/f53fxh16/)

Comment: @Icepickle do you have facebook or any other account I can contact you through (in order to solve this problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use async/await pattern, then you could change the code in your question in the following way. This will allow you to iterate the players, and once your function is completed, you can do something with the changed player data

Note, since they are references, they are changed in your original array, in case you don't want that, you could deepclone your array, and make your changes there

note that the code proposed here is based on [your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0ownf0m/) and shows an abstract way how you can change it with the async/await pattern

```js
const mockedData = [
  { player: 1, value: 1000 },
  { player: 2, value: 1500 },
  { player: 3, value: 1900 }
];

const mockedPlayers = [
  { player: 1, value: 1000 },
  { player: 2, value: 1500 },
  { player: 3, value: 1900 }
];

async function findArrayInDb(matchBy, sortBy) {
  // here you could create your db call 
  // and use the arguments for the property filtering
  // for now, always the same comes out
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve( mockedData ), 1000);
  });
}

const doDelayedPromisesWork = async (players) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    let player = players[i];
    let result;
    result = await findArrayInDb( player );
    if (player.player === result[0].player) {
      console.log('found player');
      player.value = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('player was not the first');
      player.value += 500;
    }
  }
  // no need to return, the players are reference types so they will be changed inside the for loop
};

const doPlayerMagic = async () => {
  console.log('iterating mocked players');
  var result = await doDelayedPromisesWork( mockedPlayers );
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};

doPlayerMagic().then(() => /*completed iteration of the players*/ console.log('finished'));
// runs before anything happens with the players
console.log('instructions send');
```